# Is there any word for "arbitrary selfish selections"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Media tell us facts but not all the times. They instead do a selection--based on the interests of their corporate, political parties, etc--and just tell us some of facts. Is there any word for such kind of selection?

Comment: [(Reporting) **bias**?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reporting_bias) Of course, the reason a newspaper doesn't tell you *everything* might be because [the paperboys just can't carry that much.](https://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/erik-wemple/wp/2015/09/14/new-york-times-sends-out-5-4-lb-sunday-newspapers/?utm_term=.cfa1d1f35e39)

Comment: Reporting Bias is a useful word. But is the second part of your comment really relevant. Because the question is about those selfish arbitrary selections.

Comment: I'm not sure "selfish" is necessarily relevant. Most newspapers care far more about pandering to their target readership's tastes than they do about promoting (the editor's? the proprietor's?) personal biases, 'cos if they don't do that they'll probably lose circulation and go out of business.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  By "selfish" I mean based on some interests of those who are behind the media. Pandering to targets' tastes might be part of that job. Also, they might at the same time develop some tastes in the target. And, of course, they do what they do very subtly!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called media bias; cherry picking is sifting through data or documents to find any information which you can use against your target.

Comment: Good point. After the last comment, I was highly convinced to use cherry-picking. @bvpx

Answer (score 3):

The media are **cherry-picking** the stories that air.  Defined at [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cherry%E2%80%93pick):

> to select as being the best or most desirable; also :  to select the best or most desirable from.

Further, [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cherry-pick) gives us the origin/ etymology:

> A metaphor, from the idea of picking through a bowl of cherries and seeking the best for oneself, or the idea of picking off the cherries for oneself from a cake or dessert.

Comment: Can't the sense "selecting the best or most desirable" be also for the audience when it is used for media? Because that would be the opposite of what I intend to say.

Comment: Can "cherry-picking" be used like this: Media make cherry-picking. Or Media take cherry-picks? or ... ?

Comment: I like this answer: *cherry-picking*. In your example, @Jooya, the media is selecting a subset of *cherry-picked* stories from the complete set of stories.